# Determining difference between co-ordination complexes of copper

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

What's the difference between the co-ordination compounds $\ce{Co.(H2O)6}$ and$\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^2+}$?

Comment: First one has $\ce{Co^0}$ and second one has $\ce{Co^2+}$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{Co·6H2O}$ does not exist. But, if it would exist, il would be a special sort of metallic cobalt, surrounded by 6 water molecules fixed around each $\ce{Co}$ atom. This substance would be electrically neutral. It would exist in a sample containing no other substance.

$\ce{[Co(H2O)6[^{2+}}$ does exist. It is a charged species (cation) that exists, but does not exist alone. It must be accompanied by one or several negative ion, like $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ or $\ce{2 Cl-}$. There must be the same number of positive charges and of negative charges in any sample containing this ion. So there must be as many $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^{2+}}$ cations as say $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ anions. In solution, these ions are independent and can react differently. But the number of positive charges must always be equal to the number of negative charges.

Comment: In general, how does $\ce{X.nH2O}$ differ from $\ce{X(H2O)n}$?

Comment: @Farhan S. If $\ce{H2O}$ is attached to the preceding metal $\ce{X}$, it means that there is a covalence between them. If you separate them by a point, it means that the attraction between them is weaker than a covalence, and only due to van der Wals forces.